# How to show ellipsis (three dots) at the end of a Text line in Android Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

Whether I use [androidx.compose.foundation.text.BasicText](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/text/package-summary#basictext) or [androidx.compose.material.Text](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#text), if there isn't enough space for a text it wraps to the next line, for example:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun EllipsisExample() {
    Box(modifier = Modifier.width(160.dp)) {
        Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.")
    }
}
```

renders:

[image]

How could I force it to be a single line and draw ellipsis at the end of it? The result I want in this case is something like:

> Lorem ipsum dolor s…

Answer (score 185, accepted):

Both [BasicText](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/text/package-summary#basictext) and [Text](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#text) have `overflow` and `maxLines` arguments which can help you.

```kotlin
Text(myText, maxLines = 1, overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis)
```

Here's a full single-line example:

```kotlin
import androidx.compose.material.Text
import androidx.compose.ui.text.style.TextOverflow

@Composable
fun EllipsisExample() {
    Box(modifier = Modifier.width(160.dp)) {
        Text(
            text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.",
            maxLines = 1,
            overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis
        )
    }
}
```

[image]

Of course you can tune `maxLines` to fit your needs:

```
Text(
    text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.",
    maxLines = 2,
    overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 36):

You can set the `overflow` attribute in `Text` composable to `TextOverflow.Ellipsis`
Ex:

```
Text(
    text = "Compose Previews are great to check quickly how a composable layout looks like",
    maxLines = 2,
    overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis
)
```

If you want to make the ellipsis dynamic you should use Compose's state APIs like `remember` and `mutableStateOf`, so any changes to state automatically update the UI

```
@Composable
fun MessageCard(msg: String) {
var isExpanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
Text(
     text = msg,
     modifier = Modifier.padding(all = 4.dp),
     style = MaterialTheme.typography.body2,
     maxLines = if (isExpanded) Int.MAX_VALUE else 1,
     overflow = if (isExpanded) TextOverflow.Visible else TextOverflow.Ellipsis
    )
}
```

Answer (score 9):

To show three dots , you need to give definite width param your root. In my case it is like that.

```
Column(modifier = Modifier.width(150.dp)) {
        MovieImage(
            url = movie.posterPath, modifier = Modifier
                .height(190.dp)
                .padding(8.dp)
                .clip(
                    RoundedCornerShape(CornerSize(8.dp))
                )
        )
        Text(
            text = movie.title,
            color = Color.White,
            modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp),
            maxLines = 1,
            overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis
        )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in new version of compose to set maxLines you have to use `BasicText` widget instead of `Text`

```
BasicText(
    text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.",
    maxLines = 2,
    overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis
)
```