# is it possible to wrap content where the text ends with Android compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

The composable is

```
@Preview(showBackground = true, fontScale = 2f)
@Composable
fun Test(){
    Row(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(), verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically) {
        Text(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f), text = "asjd hasjdh asjdh aksjdhaskdj haskdj")
        Icon(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(start = 4.dp)
                .size(16.dp),
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_trolley_check_circle),
            tint = MaterialTheme.textColor.success,
            contentDescription = null,
        )
    }
}
```

And the outcome is

[image]

is it possible to keep the tick where the text ended. i know the Text composable has taken the whole space. I tried weight(1f, false) as well.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to show ellipsis (three dots) at the end of a Text line in Android Jetpack Compose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65736375/how-to-show-ellipsis-three-dots-at-the-end-of-a-text-line-in-android-jetpack-c)

Comment: I dont want to discard any text. I just want to put the tick where the text ended (visually)

Comment: `Modifier.weight(1f, fill = false)` is correct here, but it doesn't work because of multiline text bug. So add `fill = false` and check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69947555/3585796)

Comment: if you dont want the space between text and Icon then remove modifier.weight(1f)

Comment: in that case, the icon wont show @Dilshad

Comment: i tried it and it worked 
check : https://pasteboard.co/uArQ4AwsLOpB.png @sadat

Comment: try more text or bigger fontscale @Dilshad

Comment: Can you add a screen of the expected result?

Answer (score -1):

You can use [FlowRow](https://google.github.io/accompanist/flowlayout/) for this purpose.

```
FlowRow {
    Text()
    Icon()
}
```

With this FlowRow, when an item width is bigger than space that is left in a row, it goes to next row.

Hence you don't need weight(1f) here.

Comment: in that case, icon may go underneath the text, isnt it?